# Explore Monero Blockchain in Ubuntu

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands, monero-research-lab

Can someone tell me step by step approach to explore Monero Blockchain in Ubuntu? From the beginning. Is there any way explore it with the terminal to see inside each block? Like what is the index of a block, transactions, previous hash, current hash etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by yourself and not rely on a block explorer, you should read the [Daemon RPC Guide](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html) and look specifically at the [get_block](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block) method.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you explore the blockchain with a browser. There are different blockchain explorers for Monero. For example:

https://chainradar.com/xmr/blocks
https://moneroblocks.info

It's pretty straight forward. You will see the block (also called 'height'), the timestamp (the block got generated), the size of that block, the number of transactions that are part of that block and the hash. You will see that for every block.

If you click on one of the rows (every row is a block) you will see the content of the block (transactions that are part of that block).

Every transaction has a hash and an amount that is usually not disclosed

Comment: Thank for reply. Yes with this weblinks I can explore the blockchain. But I want to setup blockchain on my machine and explore?